# IE6 Won't Display a Javascript Tooltip... how do you even begin to debug this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, internet-explorer-6

I am using a tooltip plugin (developed in house by someone who is on vacation) that works everywhere but in IE6. Naturally, it is being used on a site by people that use only IE6 so I need to find a way to get it displaying.

How would you even start to debug such a thing? I've Googled for the problem to see what other javascript tooltip plugins have done to deal with this but cannt find anything that pertains or solves my problem. So, I would love to debug it myself but I really don't know where to begin!

How would you start trying to crack this nut?

Some code:

In the html we insert the following (with display:none set in the css)...

```
var noteContainer = 
'<div style="float:left;" class="ttip-container">
    <div class="ttip-box">
        (<a class="ttip_heading" href="javascript:void(0)">notes</a>)
        <div class="ttip" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
            <h3>Notes</h3>
            <div class="subhead">' + noteMessage + '</div>
            <div class="subhead_bottom">Click <a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="note" noteData="' + note + '" mId="' + mId + '" visibleToM="d"><em>(notes)</em></a> to ' + actionCap + '</div>
            <img class="point" src="img/hovertip.gif" width="18" height="14" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
```

Then the plugin sets this to diplay:block on hover over an anchor link.

So... where would you start debugging an IE6 javascript issue? I have IE6 running in a VM so I can work with it... just can't get it to tell me anything about what might be going on.

Comment: Is IE throwing an error?

Comment: No, nothing. Just no tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the HTML actually being inserted into the DOM properly? If there's a parsing error the DOM methods in IE will choke (can't insert invalid HTML in IE6). This is step 1. Make sure the markup is actually there (view source is fine).

Then see if your event is firing: put an alert inside the (presumably) click handler. See if your css-changing function is actually firing.

Then see if your css-changing function has a handle on the object. Try something like `alert(this.tagName)` (or `e.tagName`, or however else you might have a handle on the element to show/hide).

Let us know how those go.

Comment: Thanks for these steps... helped me solve it. I had already done the first step before I posted here on SO. In trying to find the event that was firing I found that the tooltip was not using the plugin at all (it was loading it, but not using it), rather it had been coded to rely on the CSS pseudo-class :hover. Once I realized that it was simple to add my own JS to handle displaying the tooltip. Thanks for the steps, though, as it got me thinking and helped me solve the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Install the IE developer toolbar, and install Visual Web Developer Express (which has a real debugger)

Comment: Installer says the product isn't compatible with my operating system (XP). So... I have a Windows7 machine I can install on but then, how do I run IE6 with Web Developer Express? The only way I am aware of to get IE6 is to grab it as part of the VPC image, but that also runs XP.

Comment: VWD should work on XP.  At the very least, VWD 2008 certainly will.  You may need to install XP SP3.

Comment: Yep... looks like me not having SP3 is the problem. I'll get that and try again, thx.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would use the **IE Developer Toolbar** to see if the HTML was properly appended to the document. If it is, then we know that the problem is not with the statement you pasted into your question. If it's not in your document (in which case you're probably receiving a script error), I would try gutting your tooltip's HTML string to

```
var noteContainer = '<div style="float:left;" class="ttip-container"></div>';
```

Test if that's appended correctly. If so, progressively add more of the tooltip content until you get your error.  At that point you'll have a much better idea of what is causing IE6's parsing error.

In general, 'Old school' debugging in IE6-7 using **alert()** is still effective in many situations.

**Visual Studio** and **Visual Web Developer Express** are great options, but they're a little heavy on the system resource side, and could be annoying to work with in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Getting IE to work with JS that works in every other browser is a major pain, so my sympathies for that.

What I would do in a case like this is crack open the source that's actually generating and displaying the tooltip on the page. Throw some alerts in there or change document.title at different points in the code. See if it's even making it to the portions where a tooltip should be appearing.

If it *is* making it to the "rendering" stages of the code, change your debug setup to tell you what's inside the tooltip element, what the element's size is, etc. As much information about the tooptip container as you can gather. Something in there might stick out, like an element with 0 width/height or completely missing data.

Basically, I'd try to narrow it down to either a "data pulling" or "rendering" problem.